# Unable to view the image from library in angular applicaiton

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have create angular library with component which has image tag which uses the image from assets folder in library as below

`<img src="assets/sample.jpg"/>`

And i am trying to use the library in angular application . I could able to bundle the assets folder along with library and modified my angular.json file to have the assets option as below

{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/@uitest/ui-test/assets", "output": "/projects/ui-test-app/src/assets" }

While doing the above steps i see that the assets folder is being copied in dist folder related to angular application on building it

But if i use ng serve command to run the application in localhost the image is not loading as the assets folder is not found

Git hub link to test application to reproduce the issue https://github.com/spiderprn/ui-test.git

Comment: Have you tried <img src="~/assets/sample.json" /> or  <img src="./assets/sample.json" />?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you copy that folder to assets before serve, `npm run myServe`.

package.json of parent project:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build_lib": "ng build ui-test-app",
    "copy_files": "copy .\\projects\\ui-test-app\\src\\assets .\\dist\\assets",
    "myServe": "npm run build_lib && npm run copy_files && npm run start"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to angular.json where `<your-lib>` is the name of your library:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./node_modules/<your-lib>/assets", "output": "./assets/<your-lib>" }
],
```

For project within library use:

```
{
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "./dist/<your-lib>/assets",
  "output": "./assets/<your-lib>"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This format of `img` tag is as follows. You need to give the correct path in `src`

```
<img src="assets/sample.jpg">
```